# how to anonymously contribute to Github

Tags: opensource, git

I have noticed how important has it become to anonymously contribute to github. I have just created a new account with protonmail and removed my actual account from my Macbook. I still have the public keys. Should I use those public keys to connect my Machine to Github or generate a new pair with a new email?

What are the other things I should keep in mind to stay 100% anonymous like Satoshi Nakamoto(who created bitcoin source)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Github makes all users' public keys available at an unauthenticated endpoint: `https://github.com/username.keys` (replace `username` with your, or anyone else's, github username).

Anyone at any point in time could have scraped and saved the public keys associated with your original user. If you reuse them with your new user, the connection is easy to make.

It's simple and cheap enough to generate a new keypair for your new user. **You should generate a new keypair**.

Note: I'm intentionally ignoring "*how to stay 100% anonymous*" (this is much too broad for this forum) and "*how important it has become to anonymously contribute to github*" (this is a strange premise).